# MYSQL JOIN and DISTINCT when value is the same each time returns only 1 result

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have a table called "users" which has info(first name,etc...) with the following rows:

```
username
----------
mikha
guy
maricela
```

Another table called "questions" with the following rows:

```
asker
----------
mikha
mikha
maricela
guy
maricela
```

Another table called connections with the following rows:

```
username1
----------
guy
mikha
mikha
```

I want to select info about the user 'mikha' including count when he is questions.asker and when he is connections.username1. I use the following query:

```
SELECT COUNT(questions.asker) AS asking,COUNT(connections.username1) AS following 
FROM users LEFT JOIN questions ON users.username = questions.asker 
LEFT JOIN connections ON users.username = connections.username1 
WHERE users.username = 'mikha'
```

Expected results:

```
asking: 2 (as mikha is found 2 times asking)
following:  2 (as mikha is found 2 times following)
```

Actual results:

```
asking: 4
following: 4
```

If I use `COUNT(DISTINCT questions.asker)` and `COUNT(DISTINCT connections.username1)` I get the result always as 1 as it counts the name only once. I tried GROUP BY also with no avail.

So, how can I use distinct to avoid duplicates and the same time count the same name all the times available not just one?

I created this [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/18e2a/1) to test the problem yourself.

Thanks in advance
Regards
Michael

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have an ID in questions table, and one ID in connections table? If you have, you could use this:

```
select
  users.username,
  count(distinct questions.id) as asking,
  count(distinct connections.id) as following
from
  users left join questions on users.username = questions.asker
  left join connections on users.username = connections.username1
where
  username='mikha'
```

**EDIT:** based on your comments, i think that what you need is this:

```
select
  COUNT(distinct questions.id) AS asking,
  COUNT(DISTINCT CONCAT(c1.username1,c1.username2)) AS following,
  COUNT(DISTINCT CONCAT(c2.username1,c2.username2)) AS followers
FROM
  users LEFT JOIN questions ON questions.asker=users.username
  LEFT JOIN connections c1 ON c1.username1=users.username
  LEFT JOIN connections c2 ON c2.username2=users.username
WHERE
  users.username = 'mikha'
```

the only problem here is that counting by `CONCAT(...)` does not take advantage of indexes and can be slow. And also it could happen that `CONCAT(userA, userB) = CONCAT(userC, userD)` even if `userA<>userC and userB<>userD`. You could use `CONCAT(username1, ':', username2)` to avoid this, but only if you make sure that no username contains `:` character. But if it is possible, i would suggest you to add an `id` also to your connections table.

Comment: it will give a result of one as stated on the question :D

Comment: I have IDs for the questions but didn't add it to the query just to simplify and show you the real problem. The connections table doesn't have IDs

Comment: @KuyaJohn i'm counting `distinct ID`, not `distinct asker` or `username`, so if there's an ID available the query will give the correct result

Comment: so how do `ID` differ from `username`?

Comment: @UnhandledException `distinct questions.id` and `distinct connections.id`

Comment: @MichaelSamuel if you have an ID in your question table, you can count by distinct questions.id, but if you don't have it in connections table, you have to use a solution like the one provided by KuyaJohn

Comment: so it seems as you say...either subquery or unique ids or a separate query

Comment: @MichaelSamuel or you can count by `count(distinct concat(username1,username2)) as following` if that gives you the primary key

Comment: @ftiella: Replace those `inner` joins with `left` joins so the query works when a user has only connections or only questions.

Comment: @ftiella: thanks :) but this will work only when connections.username1 = 'mikha'. how to make it work also when connections.username2 = 'mikha'. It's a follow system like twitter so a user could be following others and get followed by others also. CONCAT will return the unique combination of the columns regardless their order. For example, it will return 1 result if (connections.username1= mikha and connections.username2 = maricela) or (connections.username1 = maricela and connections.username2 = mikha)

Comment: @MichaelSamuel did you try to use this join? `left join connections on users.username = connections.username1 or users.username = connections.username2` ? i am not sure i can understand why it doesn't work...

Comment: @ftiella: thanks again fitella for your efforts : can you take a look at this fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b2da4/4 to understand what i mean. You will find that the CONCAT returns the following and followers as the same number (2) while it should return the following as 2 and followers as 0 according to the scheme

Comment: WOOOOOOOOOW :D thanks fthiella very much :) but please could youelaborate more on what's c1 and c2. i haven't used this technique before?

Comment: @MichaelSamuel c1 and c2 are just two aliases of the connections table. Since i had to add another `left join` to count the followers, you can see that `connections` has been joined twice, and i had to distinguish between `connections` table on one join and on the other :)

Comment: yes just understood this after analyzing your updated answer and just used it on another problem that was driving me crazy :D didn't know that this is possible. Thanks fthiella REALLY for your time and effort. I appreciate it :)

Answer (score 3):

give this a shot,

```
SELECT  a.*,
        b.totalAsk AS Asking,
        c.totalCount AS following
FROM    users a
        LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT  asker, COUNT(*) totalAsk
            FROM    questions
            GROUP BY asker
        ) b ON a.username = b.asker
        LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT  username1, COUNT(*) totalCount
            FROM    connections
            GROUP BY username1
        ) c ON a.username = c.username1
WHERE   a.username = 'mikha'
```

the reason why you are getting `4` is because there are *two values* on table `questions` which matches another *two values* on table `connections` giving it 4. try calculating each values in a subquery.

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/18e2a/3)
- [SQLFiddle Demo (*an alternative solution as suggested by  `ypercube`*)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/18e2a/9)

Comment: I know it can be done with subqueries but subqueries have bad performance, is there any way to do it with left joins only and avoid the duplicated? thanks

Comment: if you have properly provided and index on those tables then it shouldn't be a problem, not all subquery have bad performance.

Comment: the table connections actually has 2 columns username1 and username2 and the primary key is the unique combination of the columns. For example, (username1:mikha,username2:maricela) (username1:maricela,username2:mikha) and so but no exact combination of the 2 columns is allowed so the (username1:mikha,username2:maricela) is allowed only once and so on.. So do you recommend a separate query or a subquery in this case? isn't there any way to join without subquery??

Comment: I would add the `WHERE asker = 'mikha'` and `WHERE username1 = 'mikha'` to the 2 subqueries. +1 from me anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the two correct answers by @fthiella and @Kuya John, here is a 3rd option, with inline subqueries:

```
SELECT  u.*,
        (   SELECT  COUNT(*) 
            FROM    questions AS q
            WHERE   u.username = q.asker 
        ) AS asking,
        (   SELECT  COUNT(*)
            FROM    connections AS c
            WHERE   u.username = c.username1
        ) AS following
FROM    users AS u
WHERE   u.username = 'mikha' ;
```